# ajax dependency selection plugin

Tags: ajax, grails, grails-plugin

Based on a previous post and some suggestions received there I have modified my application to use the ajax dependency selection plugin for some chained select lists that I have.
The select lists are Consultant -> Contract -> Project

I have a create page and edit page for an evaluation that use the same form template.  On the create page my chained selects are working correctly and saving to the database.  However when I open up an existing evaluation only the select primary select box is populated.  Do I need to do something special with this plugin to get the secondary select box values and lists populated as desired on the edit page?

Here is the code from my domain classes
Consultant domain class

```
class CdeConsultant {

String ccf_consultant_firm

static hasMany=[contracts:Contract]
static mapping = {
    table name: 'cde_consultant'
    version false
    id column: 'ccf_consultant_id', generator: "assigned"
}
}
```

Here is the code for my contract domain class

```
class Contract {

String contractName
int conId
String phone
String projectManagerName
CdeConsultant cdeConsultant
static hasMany=[projectLists:ProjectList]



    static mapping = {
        table name: 'contract'
        version false
        id column: 'contracts_id', generator: "assigned"
}
}
```

Here is the code from my ProjectList domain class
    class ProjectList {

```
String project
Contract contract


    static mapping = {
        table name: 'project_list'
        version false
        id column: 'dpp_project_phase_id', generator: "assigned"

        contract column: 'contracts_id'
}
}
```

Here is my code for the evaluation class which is where these fields are being saved

```
import java.util.Date

class CdeEvaluation extends Base {

String consultant
String consultantName
String project
String projectManager
String projectManagerPhone
String evalStatus

String cdeComment
Date evalBeginDate
Date evalEndDate
String submitApproval
int workCategory
int contract
String contractName
List<CdeEvalQuestion> questions
static hasMany = [questions: CdeEvalQuestion]

static constraints = {
    consultant(nullable:true)
    consultantName(nullable:true)
    project(nullable:true)
    contract(nullable:true)
    contractName(nullable:true)
    projectManager(nullable:true)
    projectManagerPhone(nullable:true)
    evalStatus(nullable:true)
    workCategory(nullable:true)

    evalEndDate validator: {value, cdeEvaluation -> value >= cdeEvaluation.evalBeginDate}

    cdeComment(nullable:true, maxSize:2000)
    submitApproval(nullable:true)
    evalBeginDate(blank: false, nullable:true) 
    evalEndDate(blank: false, nullable:true)


    createdBy(blank: false, nullable:true, maxSize:13)
    dateCreated(blank: false, nullable:true)
    lastUpdatedBy(blank: false, nullable:true, maxSize:13)
    lastUpdated(blank: false, nullable:true)

}

static mapping = {
    table name: 'CDE_EVALUATION'
    id column: 'ceval_id_seq'
    id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'ceval_id_seq']
}

 @Override
public String toString() {
    "${project}"
}


class EvaluationController {
    static scaffold=true
}
```

}

And finally here is the code for my form template that is used in both the create and edit pages.

```
 <g:selectPrimary class="form-select-list" id="consultant" name="consultant" label="Consultant"
    domain='gov.mt.mdt.cde.domain.evaluation.CdeConsultant'
    searchField="ccf_consultant_firm"
    collectField='id'

    domain2='gov.mt.mdt.cde.domain.evaluation.Contract'
    bindid="cdeConsultant.id"
    searchField2='contractName'
    collectField2='id'


    noSelection="['': 'Select A Consultant']" 
    setId="contract"
    value="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.consultant}"


    appendValue=''
        appendName='Select a Contract' />

    <g:selectSecondary class="form-select-list" id="contract" name="contract"
        domain2='gov.mt.mdt.cde.domain.evaluation.ProjectList'
        bindid="contract.id"
        searchField2='project'
        collectField2='project'


        noSelection="['': 'Select A Contract']"
        setId="project"

        appendValue=''
        appendName='Select a Project'

        value="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.contract}"
required="false"/>


 <g:select class="form-control" name="project" id="project" optionKey="project"    optionValue="project"
        from="[]"  noSelection="['': 'Select A Project']" value="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.project}" />
```

Comment: 0.40 has been released that addresses this issue - please review answer below (about to be updated with how to)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry a little late to answer your question here, edit I don't think has much documentation :). Although current situation gives me ideas to expand on the plugin for sure...

The problem being the secondary selection is reliant on primary being selected, the selection on primary itself triggers the gathered list for secondary box to be populated. Since primary is already defined not selected - well there you see the issue.

Let me have a think, if you had raised it as issue/suggestion on github I would have got to it earlier.

**UPDATE**

Ok I have rolled out 0.40 which should hopefully address edit mode :

Please take a look at this page :

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselectexample/blob/master/grails-app/views/myContinent/testedit.gsp

In theory assuming the hardcoded values are returned as dynamic variables from the db an additional definition is required per primary/secondary call:

so in the

```
  value='4'
  secondaryValue='10'
```

**Value** is its own value and **secondaryValue** is what you expect to set the next selectSecondary

Please note I had to also remove appendName and appendValue from selectPrimary/selectSecondary calls. I think there was some form of a conflict in the edit mode....

Anyhow that testedit appeared to be working.